# SQL Server Group By Excluding Some Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have some records like below:

```
ID Val Amount
1  0   3
2  0   3
3  0   4
4  1   2
5  1   3
6  2   3
7  2   4
```

I want to group this data by the column Val and get the sum(amount), but do not group the ones with Val = 0.

The result set I need is like below:

```
Val Amount
0   3
0   3
0   4
1   5
2   7
```

I did it by two ways, but none seem to be the best way:

First one is by using unions, like, first having the ones with Val = 0, then grouping the ones with Val <> 0 and unioning the two result sets.

Second one is a little bit better. Let's call the data we have is in the table @Table:

```
WITH g AS
(
SELECT Val, Amount, CASE WHEN Val = '0' then Val + ID
      else Val END A FROM @table 
)
SELECT CASE WHEN A LIKE '0%' THEN 0 ELSE A END AS A, SUM(Amount)
FROM g
GROUP BY A
```

This also works, but being have to concatenate with the ID column (or raw_number) and than using a left function to remove it is not a best practice.

So I'm looking for a better approach, both looking better and performing better as well.

I work on SQL Server 2008, but I'm open to any solutions which require newer versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest way of doing it is the following:

```
SELECT Val, SUM(Amount)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Val, CASE WHEN Val = 0 THEN ID ELSE 0 END
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/02d72/8)

You can also do it using window functions:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT ID, Val, Amount,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Val 
                             ORDER BY CASE 
                                         WHEN Val = 0 THEN ID 
                                         ELSE 0 
                                      END) AS rank
  FROM mytable
) 
SELECT Val, SUM(Amount) AS total_amount
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Val, rank
```

The result set returned by the `CTE` is:

```
ID  Val Amount  rank
--------------------
1   0   3       1
2   0   3       2
3   0   4       3
4   1   2       1
5   1   3       1
6   2   3       1
7   2   4       1
```

So using `rank` you can differentiate between `0` and the rest of `Val` values.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/02d72/6)

You can use both methods and see how they compare to each other in terms of performance.

Comment: Your first query should be the accepted answer, I think +1.  But not the second one.

Comment: Super elegant answer, the first one! The second one is an upgrade of my approach I suppose, and It also works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use a union here.  The top of the below union finds aggregate amounts of values which are not zero, and the bottom brings in the zero value records, not aggregated.

```
SELECT Val, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM g
WHERE Val <> 0
GROUP BY Val
UNION ALL
SELECT Val, Amount
FROM g
WHERE Val = 0
ORDER BY Val;
```

### Demo

Comment: I'm looking for solutions without unions as I stated in the question. But, do you recommend using unions for performance as well?

Comment: A union is the logically correct thing here, because you are aggregating part of the table, but not the other.  For a slick answer, check the first query given by @giorgos